# Clear Jquery animate distance after each function trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to make a simple sticky header that will follow the user down the page as they scroll.

So far I have:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
      var topmarg = $(document).scrollTop();    
      $('#stickyheader').animate({ marginTop : "+=" + topmarg + "px" }, "slow" );
  });
```

Which works, but it seems to 'add' the amounts to `marginTop`, so, for example, if I scroll down 200px then back up 100px the `#stickyheader` will actually move 300px down the page, rather then 200 down then 100 back up.

Is there a way to ammend this? Should I be using `.css()` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var lastscroll=0;
    $(document).scroll(function() {

    var topmarg = $(document).scrollTop(); 
if(topmarg>lastscroll){             
      $('#stickyheader').animate({ marginTop : "+=" + topmarg + "px" }, "slow" );
}else{

     $('#stickyheader').animate({ marginTop :  topmarg + "px" }, "slow" );
}
  lastscroll =topmarg;

});
```

Comment: Thanks! I added `modscroll = topmarg - lastscroll;` as the scroll down was still having issues